# Can fourier transform of a function with not empty support be zero on whole range?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

We consider $f : [a, b] \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$  and support may consist of only one point.

Comment: All functions that vanish outside a set of measure zero are mapped to the zero function by the Fourier transform, and by the uniqueness theorem these are the only ones that are mapped to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can, any function which has a null set as support has zero Fourier transform. This is easy to see from the fact that the Fourier transform is a unitary operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$.